# Cannot get table height to contstrain with in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've played around with a number of options, but I can't keep the table height from growing as I add lines dynamically.

This is a small section, part of a more complex page. Basically I have several div tags within the larger container div.

As more lines are added the table pushes the button below outside the boundaries of the div.  Run the code snippet to observe the problem.

```js
function onBodyLoader(obj) {
  g.c.assignEventListners();
}
var g = {};

g.formClass = function() {
  /*
  ----------------------------------
  Properties for formClass
  ----------------------------------
  */
  this.tr;
  this.td;
  this.elist = [];

  /*
  ----------------------------------
  Methods for formClass
  ----------------------------------
  */

  this.assignEventListners = function() {
    this.tbody = document.getElementById('emailDist');

    g.sbAddELine = document.getElementById('sbAddELine');
    g.sbAddELine.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
      g.c.addBlank();
    }, false);

    /*event listener for all links on the email list body*/
    g.dataUpdate = document.querySelector("#emailDist");
    g.dataUpdate.addEventListener("click", g.c.tableBodyRouter, false);

  };

  this.tableBodyRouter = function(e) {
    /*
    called from clicks on keyTable or task links
    */
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget)
      if (e.target.id.indexOf('eRemove') > -1)
        g.c.removeEmail(e);
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  this.redrawElist = function() {

    /*delete current table*/
    while (this.tbody.rows.length > 1)
      this.tbody.deleteRow(1);

    /*redraw table*/
    for (var i = 0; i < this.elist.length; i++) {
      this.rowLayout();
    }
  };

  this.addBlank = function() {
    /*add blank to this.elist array*/
    this.elist.push({
      eEmail: '',
      eFirst: '',
      eLast: '',
    });

    this.rowLayout();

  }
  this.removeEmail = function(e) {
    var x = e.target.id.substr(7);

    this.elist.splice(x, 1);
    this.redrawElist();

  };

  this.rowLayout = function() {
    var rowCnt = this.tbody.rows.length - 1;
    this.tr = this.tbody.insertRow(this.tbody.rows.length);

    this.td = this.tr.insertCell(this.tr.cells.length);
    this.td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="eFirst' + rowCnt + '" maxlength="20" size="20" value=""/>';

    this.td = this.tr.insertCell(this.tr.cells.length);
    this.td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="eLast' + rowCnt + '" maxlength="20" size="20" value="" />';

    this.td = this.tr.insertCell(this.tr.cells.length);
    this.td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="eEmail' + rowCnt + '" maxlength="50" size="50" value="" />';

    this.td = this.tr.insertCell(this.tr.cells.length);
    this.td.innerHTML = '<input type="button"  id="eRemove' + rowCnt + '" value="Remove" ">';
    document.getElementById("eFirst" + rowCnt).focus();
    document.getElementById("eFirst" + rowCnt).select();
  }

}
g.c = new g.formClass;
```

```css
table {
  height: 60%;
  max-height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-table;
  border-style: none;
}

tbody {
  font-size: 10pt;
  display: block;
  height: 90%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 98%;
  top: 40px;
  height: 90%;
}

#dataEntryDiv {
  border: medium groove;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  height: 95%;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Email List</title>
</head>

<body id="intactRolesBody" onLoad="onBodyLoader(this);">
  <form id='intactRolesForm' method="post" action="" onSubmit="return false;">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="dataEntryDiv">
        <input type="button" id='sbAddELine' value="Add non-company contact"><br>
        <p>Email Distribution List</p>
        <table>
          <tbody id='emailDist'>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>email</th>
              <th>remove from list</th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="button" id='SaveEmailList' value="Save email List">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What about adding ```overflow: hidden;``` style to your table?

Comment: Will not work to keep the size of the table constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic behavior of a table. it shrinks and expand acording to its content.

What you can do to manage height is to reset the display.
it can be anything but  table/inline-table/table-cell/table-row/.. . nor inline.

You used inline-table, inline-block might be fine:

```js
function onBodyLoader(obj) {
  g.c.assignEventListners();
}
var g = {};

g.formClass = function() {
  /*
  ----------------------------------
  Properties for formClass
  ----------------------------------
  */
  this.tr;
  this.td;
  this.elist = [];

  /*
  ----------------------------------
  Methods for formClass
  ----------------------------------
  */

  this.assignEventListners = function() {
    this.tbody = document.getElementById('emailDist');

    g.sbAddELine = document.getElementById('sbAddELine');
    g.sbAddELine.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
      g.c.addBlank();
    }, false);

    /*event listener for all links on the email list body*/
    g.dataUpdate = document.querySelector("#emailDist");
    g.dataUpdate.addEventListener("click", g.c.tableBodyRouter, false);

  };

  this.tableBodyRouter = function(e) {
    /*
    called from clicks on keyTable or task links
    */
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget)
      if (e.target.id.indexOf('eRemove') > -1)
        g.c.removeEmail(e);
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  this.redrawElist = function() {

    /*delete current table*/
    while (this.tbody.rows.length > 1)
      this.tbody.deleteRow(1);

    /*redraw table*/
    for (var i = 0; i < this.elist.length; i++) {
      this.rowLayout();
    }
  };

  this.addBlank = function() {
    /*add blank to this.elist array*/
    this.elist.push({
      eEmail: '',
      eFirst: '',
      eLast: '',
    });

    this.rowLayout();

  }
  this.removeEmail = function(e) {
    var x = e.target.id.substr(7);

    this.elist.splice(x, 1);
    this.redrawElist();

  };

  this.rowLayout = function() {
    var rowCnt = this.tbody.rows.length - 1;
    this.tr = this.tbody.insertRow(this.tbody.rows.length);

    this.td = this.tr.insertCell(this.tr.cells.length);
    this.td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="eFirst' + rowCnt + '" maxlength="20" size="20" value=""/>';

    this.td = this.tr.insertCell(this.tr.cells.length);
    this.td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="eLast' + rowCnt + '" maxlength="20" size="20" value="" />';

    this.td = this.tr.insertCell(this.tr.cells.length);
    this.td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="eEmail' + rowCnt + '" maxlength="50" size="50" value="" />';

    this.td = this.tr.insertCell(this.tr.cells.length);
    this.td.innerHTML = '<input type="button"  id="eRemove' + rowCnt + '" value="Remove" ">';
    document.getElementById("eFirst" + rowCnt).focus();
    document.getElementById("eFirst" + rowCnt).select();
  }

}
g.c = new g.formClass;
```

```css
  table {
    height: 60%;
    max-height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;/*... or block : do not use table display if you need to constrain height */
    border-style: none;
  }
  
  tbody {/* this CSS could have been set to table directly :) */
    font-size: 10pt;
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  
  #container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 98%;
    top: 40px;
    height: 90%;
  }
  
  #dataEntryDiv {
    border: medium groove;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
    /*left: 37em; removed for demo */
    height: 95%;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<body id="intactRolesBody" onLoad="onBodyLoader(this);">
  <form id='intactRolesForm' method="post" action="" onSubmit="return false;">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="dataEntryDiv">
        <input type="button" id='sbAddELine' value="Add non-company contact"><br>
        <p>Email Distribution List</p>
        <table>
          <tbody id='emailDist'>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>email</th>
              <th>remove from list</th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="button" id='SaveEmailList' value="Save email List">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

---

Note: You did use `display:block` on `tbody`, you could have apply this directly to the `table` element and reset `tbody` to `display:table` :) (defaut is `table-row-group` )

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I ran your code snippet in full screen mode and saw that it accomplished everything I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#dataEntryDiv {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,  I fear I need more that this.  Please note I used overflow-y to control only the vertical.

Answer (score 0):

To get a simplified version of the situation, I would suggest writing something like this - instead of putting in the code from your actual project. This way, you can get away from trying to 'fix' something - and possibly see a better way to build the layout - or at least make the use-case more specific.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

markup

```
<section class="table-wrapper">
  <header>
    I'm a table wrapper thing
  </header>

  <main>
    <table>
      <!-- populate this -->
    </table>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <button>button (add row)</button>
  </footer>
</section>
```

styles

```
.table-wrapper {
  height: 300px; /* arbitrary */
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.table-wrapper main {
  height: 260px; /* likely you'd use flexbox or percentages or JS */
  border: 2px solid blue;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

js

```
var $table = $('.table-wrapper').find('table');
var $moreButton = $('.table-wrapper').find('button');

var counter = 0;

function addRow() {
  counter = counter + 1;
  $table.prepend('<tr><td>row and data ' + counter + '</td></tr>');
}

addRow();
// populate some things to start

$moreButton.on('click', function() {
  addRow();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/b6z4ep46/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I get what you are saying about simplifying my question, good point and that was what I was trying to do.  I don't do jQuery so I cannot implement your solution.  Also, as I need to track other information on the dynamic list, I noted that your example added the new lines to the top of the table with the prepend method which makes it more difficult for me to track deletions from the list.  However, I did note that your solution did maintain the height of the table and it's container.  Again thank you for your help.

Comment: The concepts are not jQuery specific. You can change prepend to append.  I'm sure you can see the points made and the layout choices - and apply it to your project. : )  Good luck!